# Number of integer coefficient multilinear polynomials

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for an expression for number of multilinear polynomials of degree atmost $t$ in $n$ variables with integer coefficients having coefficient size atmost $|B|$.

Is $(2|B|+1)^{\sum_{i=t_1}^{t_2}{n\choose i}}\sim (2|B|+1)^{(\frac{n}{t+1})^{t+1}}$ a good approximation?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow  coefficients for the polynomials to range among a set of size $b$ (you say $b=2|B|+1$) and there are $c$ configurations for the exponents of the polynomials, then there will be $b^c$ such polynomials. To count the configurations for the exponents, let's first count those with $n$ variables with a degree of exactly $d$. By the "stars and bars" argument, there are $\binom{n+d-1}{n-1}$ such configurations for the exponents. To have a degree of at most $t$, you need the sum $\sum_{d=0}^t \binom{n+d-1}{n-1}$. This sum is $\binom{n+t}{n}$, which is sometimes called the "hockey stick lemma". So, the total number of polynomials of degree at most $t$ in $n$ variables with coefficients at most $|B|$ in absolute value is
$$(2|B|+1)^{ \binom{n+t}{n}}.$$